Finding Basis of a Linear Subspace
Which of the following set of vectors is a basis for:
`
$$V= \{(v_1,v_2,v_3)\mid v_1+v_2-v_3=0\}^T$$
$1$ - $\{(1,0,0), (0, 1,1)\}^T$
$2$ - $\{(1,0,1), (1,1,2)\}^T$
$3$ - $\{(1,1,2), (0, 1,1),(1,0,1)\}^T$
$4$ - $\{(1,0,0), (0, 1,0),(0,0,1)\}^T$
$5$ - $\{(1,-1,0), (2, 1,3)\}^T$
I have tried to find the linear independence. Like for example for the first one, they are linearly independent, but there are only $2$ vectors given on the set, if we consider them $v_1$ and $v_2$, how can we determine the $v_3$? Can it be a combination of them? If so how can I apply the condition given as $v_1+v_2-v_3=0$ on it? Can someone explain it to me, please?

Can you see that $(1,0,0)$ is not in $V$, because $1+0-0\ne0$?

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

OMG! You are kidding right? That's it.
So it is just me overthink this. :I

You seem to be mixing up whether we are talking about a first vector... like the first vector of $(1,0,1),(1,1,2)$ being $(1,0,1)$.... and if we are talking about the first entry of a vector... the first entry of $(1,0,1)$ being $1$.  Here... $V$ is the set of all vectors where for each vector... the first entry plus the second entry minus the third entry is equal to zero.

The third vector in 3 is the first vector minus the second, so they are not linearly independent, so they are not a basis

@JMoravitz's comment could be (the beginning of) an answer. In addition to J.W.Tanner's first comment, which discards 1 and 4, you perhaps know why $\dim(V)=3-1=2$ (subspace defined by 1 equation in a space of dimension 3), which discards 4 again, and also 3. There only remains to check that in 2 and 5, the two vectors belong to $V$ and are independent.

I assume that
$$V=\{(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in\Bbb R^3\mid v_1+v_2-v_3=0\},$$
which is the same as
$$V=\{(v_1,v_2,v_1+v_2)\mid v_1,v_2\in\Bbb R\}.$$
Since $(1,0,0)\notin V$, because $1+0-0\neq 0$, it follows that the sets $1$ and $4$ can not be bases for $V$.
Now, if $x\in V$, then
\begin{align}
x=(v_1,v_2,v_1+v_2)&=v_1(1,0,1)+v_2(0,1,1)\\
&=(v_1-v_2)(1,0,1)+v_2(1,1,2)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{3}v_1-\frac{2}{3}v_2\right)(1,-1,0)+\left(\frac{1}{3}v_1+\frac{1}{3}v_2\right)(2,1,3).
\end{align}
Thus, $\{(1,0,1),(1,1,2)\}$ and $\{(1,-1,0),(2,1,3)\}$ are spanning sets of $V$. Futhermore, these sets are linearly independent. Therefore, the sets $2$ and $5$ are bases for $V$, which means that $\dim V=2$. Therefore, the set $3$ can not be a basis for $V$.
In summary, only the sets $2$ and $5$ are bases for $V$.
